# Error while using Flutter with Riverpod and null safety

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using Flutter with Riverpod and null safety for the first time and I have the following provider that should return ImageProfile or null.

```
final myProfileImageProvider = Provider.autoDispose.family<ProfileImage?, int>(
  (ref, index) {
    final images = ref.watch(editMyProfileViewModelProvider.state).images;
    if (index < images.length) {
      return images[index];
    }
    return null;
  },
  name: 'myProfileImageProvider',
);
```

I am reading the provider inside a function like this:

```
final profileImage = context.read<ProfileImage>(myProfileImageProvider(profileImageIndex));
```

But I am getting the following compiler error.

```
The argument type 'AutoDisposeProvider<ProfileImage?>' can't be assigned to the parameter 
type 'ProviderBase<Object, ProfileImage?>' because 'ProfileImage?' is nullable and 'Object' 
isn't.
```

Notice that inside a function, I can't use watch or useProvider.  I must use context.read. Please note that useProvider() does solve the problem but can't use it inside a function.  The problem is when reading the provider inside a function.

Any body out there know the answer to this?
I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: make int nullable and lets see

Comment: Making int nullable does not help. If I used  useProvider(myProfileImageProvider(myProfileImageIndex)); then it will work.  But but can't call useProvider inside a function.

Comment: Are you depending on a null-safe version of the provider package?

Comment: Yes, I am using null-safety version of Flutter Riverpod.